# Problem with adobe PDF preview and indesign colour calibration

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, pdf, export, calibration

[image]

I've been trying to work this one out today to no avail.

**The 15 image on the right is how adobe pdf viewer and Indesign CC display my file.
The 15 on the left is how it prints; I can only seem to display the 'true' colours by opening the pdf in a web browser, as opposed to adobe programs.**

If anyone has a bright idea as to why Indesign, and then adobe reader isn't displaying the true colours, I'd be much obliged.

The colour is the same on both my mac at work and my home pc.

Comment: Prints where? Your inkjet? Offset press?

Comment: Offset press.  The colour is similar to the 15 on the right in InDesign file itself. I then export to PDF/x-1a and it comes out the same. It prints like the 15 on the left. When I preview the PDF in apple preview at work it is closer to the 15 on the left.

Comment: Spot color? CMYK? RGB?? Indesign blending space??? More info is needed.

Comment: Sorry Scott. It's a CMYK navy blue. the blending space is set to CMYK

Comment: The first rule of `pdf` viewers: not a single one is able to reliably display a print-ready, CMYK `pdf` on screen. Please also remember that what you're seeing on-screen is an RGB approximation of a CMYK approximation. I've learned to go with my gut.

Comment: @Vincent. Thank you. yeah those are all good points. My confusion/frustration is born from the fact that the image on the left is how it looked on screen via apple preview and web browser and is also how it printed at the printers via offset. The one on the right is how it looked on Indesign and PDF reader on screen. There's a significant difference between the two onscreen.